# What is the main difference between MDM and ESB?

Tags: esb, master-data-management

I have read a few articles online, but I'm still pretty confused. What is the main difference between ESB - mediator and MDM?

Is MDM (Master Data Management) just a subset of ESB (Enterprise Service Bus)? Is the ESB just the underlying technology with IT governance support for connecting systems, while the MDM is just syncing the data within the systems? Do both architectures have their own dashboard?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ESB is an integration solution which makes it possible to connect systems in a loosely coupled way.

MDM is a concept which ensures that organization's key business information (master data) is provided to all relevant systems and users in a consistent way. (MDM can utilize ESB in data integration and communication.) 
For MDM I recommend to read www.whatismdm.com It has a good overview about MDM and links to good MDM articles.